# Display non search results in Drupal 7

Tags: search

I've been looking for a way to show all taxonomy terms that are not searched for in a view.

What I mean is: I want a search to sort out safe food for customers that are allergic to some food. If a customer is allergic to nuts the customer type nuts in the form and the customer gets a list of all dishes that DON'T contain nuts. Anyone know a module that will help me do this?

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can do this with [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views).

1. [Build a view](https://www.drupalgardens.com/documentation/views/create) that displays your dishes.
2. Set a *FILTER* for 'Has taxonomy term', expose it, and use the 'is none of' operator

[image: Has taxonomy term example]

I made that example using the 'dropdown' option, you may find the 'autocomplete' option more suitable to your needs.  I recommend trying both to see which fits best and allowing multiple values so that people who are allergic to nuts AND gluten can still use it.